# Why text and input on same line?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23062/).

Here is HTML and bootstrap3:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I expect that text and input will be on the same line, why text and inputs not on the same line, what do I missing?

Comment: expand the jsfiddle's preview windows's width. For me the label and input box are on the same line.

Comment: i updated the fiddle with your code and its working, the thing your missing might be the bootstrap library. You forgot to include it

Comment: @Sherlock and that is why I wasn't able to see the problem. xD

Comment: @GandalftheWhite yes unless he wraps each control with `<div class="row">`